# Are there any radix/patricia/critbit trees for Python?

Tags: python, patricia-trie

I have about 10,000 words used as a set of inverted indices to about 500,000 documents. Both are normalized so the index is a mapping of integers (word id) to a set of integers (ids of documents which contain the word).

My prototype uses Python's set as the obvious data type.

When I do a search for a document I find the list of N search words and their corresponding N sets. I want to return the set of documents in the intersection of those N sets.

Python's "intersect" method is implemented as a pairwise reduction. I think I can do better with a parallel search of sorted sets, so long as the library offers a fast way to get the next entry after *i*.

I've been looking for something like that for some time. Years ago I wrote [PyJudy](http://www.dalkescientific.com/Python/PyJudy.html) but I no longer maintain it and I know how much work it would take to get it to a stage where I'm comfortable with it again. I would rather use someone else's well-tested code, and I would like one which supports fast serialization/deserialization.

I can't find any, or at least not any with Python bindings. There is [avltree](http://www.pardon-sleeuwaegen.be/antoon/avltree.py) which does what I want, but since even the pair-wise set merge take longer than I want, I suspect I want to have all my operations done in C/C++.

Do you know of any radix/patricia/critbit tree libraries written as C/C++ extensions for Python?

Failing that, what is the most appropriate library which I should wrap? The [Judy Array](http://judy.sourceforge.net/) site hasn't been updated in 6 years, with 1.0.5 released in May 2007. (Although it does build cleanly so perhaps It Just Works.)

(Edit: to clarify what I'm looking for from an API, I want something like:

```
def merge(document_sets):
    probe_i = 0
    probe_set = document_sets[probe_i]
    document_id = GET_FIRST(probe_set)

    while IS_VALID(document_id):
        # See if the document is present in all sets
        for i in range(1, len(document_sets)):
            # dynamically adapt to favor the least matching set
            target_i = (i + probe_i) % len(document_sets)
            target = document_sets[target_i]
            if document_id not in target_set:
                probe_i = target_id
                probe_set = document_sets[probe_i]
                document_id = GET_NEXT(probe_set, document_id)
                break
        else:
            yield document_id
```

I'm looking for something which implements GET_NEXT() to return the next entry which occurs after the given entry. This corresponds to [Judy1N](http://judy.sourceforge.net/doc/Judy1_funcs_3x.htm#Judy1Next) and the similar entries for other Judy arrays.

This algorithm dynamically adapts to the data should preferentially favor sets with low hits. For the type of data I work with this has given a [5-10% increase in performance](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2005/03/02/faster_fingerprint_substructure_tests.html).)
)

Comment: Just in case: take a look at http://www.nltk.org/ if you did not yet.

Comment: I have not. A quick scan doesn't find anything relevant. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Do you really need a generator or are you ultimately interested in just getting a set/list of the document numbers?

Comment: @Justin: All I need is the final set. The example here was to show how I think I can take advantage of an ordered set to make a faster intersection function. Without an iterator then some rare cases might return a 15 million set intersection, but that's not a serious concern for my problem.

Comment: Sets really are the way to go here. The problem is the way that multi-set intersections are implemented such that (N-1) sets are made. That is the source of the huge slowdown. I would personally just make my own (C) version of set based that in the Python distribution. I also think that this should be a requested change in the Python distributions. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Justin: I do plan to propose/implement this, plus a new function. There should also be a (has, has_not) = set.split(iterable) where "has" has all the elements of "set" which are in the iterable, with the other "set" elements go into "has_not". I'm using 2.6 and I looked at the 2.7 source to see its implementation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are some, <strike>though I'm not sure if they're suitable for your use case:</strike> but it seems none of them are what you asked for.

[BioPython](http://biopython.org/) has a Trie implementation in C.

Ah, here's a nice discussion including benchmarks: http://bugs.python.org/issue9520

Other (some very stale) implementations:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/radix

> py-radix is an implementation of a
>   radix tree data structure for the
>   storage and retrieval of IPv4 and IPv6
>   network prefixes.

https://bitbucket.org/markon/patricia-tree/src

> A Python implementation of
>   patricia-tree

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/trie

> A prefix tree (trie) implementation.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/logilab-common/0.50.3

> patricia.py : A Python implementation
>   of PATRICIA trie (Practical Algorithm
>   to Retrieve Information Coded in
>   Alphanumeric).

Comment: Biopython's trie doesn't support a "get next entry after i" in the API. Radix is specifically for IPv4/6 formatted addresses and not a general purpose library. Trie is (as you say) pure Python and it does not have a "get next" interface. "patricia.py" is noticeably missing from the logilab repository.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently added iteration support to [datrie](https://github.com/kmike/datrie), you may give it a try.

Comment: Sadly, crashes for me, python 3.3, win7 32-bit, datrie 0.4.2, I try to run example code given at the github page. :-/

Comment: Application crash when loading datrie: c0000374, looks like a heap corruption.

Comment: Can you please fire an issue in the bug tracker? Is the alphabet set properly?

Comment: As far as I can remember I set 'abcdef' as alphabet and only added t['a'] = 'a', t['b'] = 'b' etc. with t being a Trie. I will try to elaborate this soon, I have removed datrie for now and will install it tonight again tonight. I use mingw 4.6.2 win32 to compile.