# Reduce list based off of element substrings

Tags: python

I'm looking for the most efficient way to reduce a given list based off of substrings already in the list.

For example

```
mylist = ['abcd','abcde','abcdef','qrs','qrst','qrstu']
```

would be reduced to:

```
mylist = ['abcd','qrs']
```

because both 'abcd' and 'qrs' are the smallest substring of other elements in that list. I was able to do this with about 30 lines of code, but I suspect there is a crafty one-liner out there..

Comment: At a high level, it's simple: build a [radix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree), then take the direct children of the root (that represent actual elements; a node is just a maximal common prefix of its desendents). In practice, you'll need to track down a decent implementation of a radix tree. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707296/are-there-any-radix-patricia-critbit-trees-for-python) might help you start.

Comment: can you provide more complex example for tests?

Comment: Are substrings always supposed to be prefixes?

Comment: yes, they are always meant to be prefixes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this seems to be working (but not so efficient i suppose)

```
def reduce_prefixes(strings):
    sorted_strings = sorted(strings)
    return [element
            for index, element in enumerate(sorted_strings)
            if all(not previous.startswith(element) and
                   not element.startswith(previous)
                   for previous in sorted_strings[:index])]
```

tests:

```
>>>reduce_prefixes(['abcd', 'abcde', 'abcdef',
                    'qrs', 'qrst', 'qrstu'])
['abcd', 'qrs']
>>>reduce_prefixes(['abcd', 'abcde', 'abcdef',
                    'qrs', 'qrst', 'qrstu',
                    'gabcd', 'gab', 'ab'])
['ab', 'gab', 'qrs']
```

Comment: Pre-sorting the strings is a clever trick, which probably speeds it up considerably compared to my naive solution.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to iterate over all the strings and split them based on if they had different characters, and recursively apply that function.

```
def reduce_substrings(strings):
    return list(_reduce_substrings(map(iter, strings)))

def _reduce_substrings(strings):
    # A dictionary of characters to a list of strings that begin with that character
    nexts = {}
    for string in strings:
        try:
            nexts.setdefault(next(string), []).append(string)
        except StopIteration:
            # Reached the end of this string. It is the only shortest substring.
            yield ''
            return
    for next_char, next_strings in nexts.items():
        for next_substrings in _reduce_substrings(next_strings):
            yield next_char + next_substrings
```

This splits it into a dictionary based on the character, and tries to find the shortest substring out of those that it split into a different list in the dictionary.

Of course, because of the recursive nature of this function, a one-liner wouldn't be possible as efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient, but at least short:

```
mylist = ['abcd','abcde','abcdef','qrs','qrst','qrstu']

outlist = []
for l in mylist:
    if any(o.startswith(l) for o in outlist):
        # l is a prefix of some elements in outlist, so it replaces them
        outlist = [ o for o in outlist if not o.startswith(l) ] + [ l ]
    if not any(l.startswith(o) for o in outlist):
        # l has no prefix in outlist yet, so it becomes a prefix candidate
        outlist.append(l)

print(outlist)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
import re
mylist = ['abcd','abcde','abcdef','qrs','qrst','qrstu']
new_list=[]
for i in mylist:
    if re.match("^abcd$",i):
        new_list.append(i)
    elif re.match("^qrs$",i):
        new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
#['abcd', 'qrs']
```

Comment: this assumes the values of the list are known. Values will be unknown and the values must not have other items in the list that are substrings of that item

Comment: I got it. Thank you.